# Angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular.  Just trying to replicate this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4499/) to play with nodes, but the angular is not working. First, the jsfiddle is confusing my as the application names are not he same.  Secondly, it looks like and old version.  What am I doing wrong when setting up the application.  Is something missing with the templates, or the order of scripts out of place?

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc8.js"></script>

  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: circle;
  }
  li {
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
  </style>


</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
      {{data.name}}
      <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
      <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
      </ul>
  </script>

  <ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
      <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
  angular.module("myApp", []).
  controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.delete = function(data) {
          data.nodes = [];
      };
      $scope.add = function(data) {
          var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
          var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
          data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: []});
      };
      $scope.tree = [{name: "Simon", nodes: []}];
  }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're trying to learn angular, you may want to start with angular 2+ and not angularjs (unless you're trying to learn it for a job/project that uses it). https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: I was going to rewrite this to angular 2, after I got it to work.

Comment: angularjs and angular2 are very very different. Angular2 is a total rewrite of angular and a lot of concepts from angularjs don't carry over to angular 2. But to help you out with angularjs, I am noticing that you're pulling down a very very old version of angularjs. Here's the link to the latest source: https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular.js

Answer (score 1):

`ng-app`should target a module. Try `ng-app="myApp"`.

Comment: That's what I thought. However in the fiddle it works.

Comment: In the fiddle the module name and the `ng-app` expression matches, 
`angular.module("Application", [])` and `ng-app="Application"`. The module name can be chosen as you like. It just needs to match the `ng-app` expression.

Comment: Sorry, I changed that.  The fiddle actually doesn't work when those are matching.  See again. It's real weird.